# Review Reopen queue without reason

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

I'm reviewing Reopen queue, and sometimes like the [latest](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/18461904), There's no reason why to consider reopen the question or no apparent edit.

> Should this question be reopened?
>   It was initially closed as unclear what you're asking

How should I approach it? as a new question? should I read all the comments and find why the question is eligible for reopen?

I try to read all the comments, but I guess I'm missing a sentence of reasoning.

Usually there's a change of an edit, but if there's no change, why should we reopen it? even if we reopen it, it can be closed again for the same reason as before.

Comment: Looks like an audit to me...

Comment: If you're unsure, skip.

Comment: Usually there's a change of an edit, but if there's no change, why should we reopen it? it can be closed again

Comment: @user7294900 why would you want to have that question closed? It's a perfectly fine [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897716/can-i-bind-a-constructors-prototype-methods-to-constructed-instances-while-keep).

Comment: I don't want it to be closed, the users who closed it will close it again if it will be reopened without a change

Comment: Noone's closed it. It was [deleted, undeleted and edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47897716/revisions). Like I suspected that was just an audit, which would be why it was in the queue.

Comment: This specific question was an audit, but I got other questions in reopen queue which had no edit

Comment: My bad then, I thought you were asking about the review you linked to.

Comment: @user7294900 while an initial edit will put a closed post into the reopen queue, it can also be put in the reopen queue by people casting a reopen vote on it whether its edited or not as they supposedly feel it shouldn't have been closed but doesn't need any edits done to it.

Comment: @Jon Clements Arguendo, It seems that 5 users can reopen and 5 users can close it multiple times because question didn't change

Comment: @user7294900 a user can vote to close/reopen once per question. There's nothing to stop a user from having participated in closing a question, realise maybe it shouldn't have been and voting to reopen which'll put it in the queue even if the question hasn't changed. If you don't think it requires reopening, then review it as leave closed.

Comment: @Jon Clements I didn't know that "user can vote to close/reopen once per question", why aren't you answering?

Comment: Right now - because I'm fairly sure this has come up and been explained before and more thoroughly than I have... I'll have a look for that and if I can't find it - I or someone can answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deciding if a question should be reopened or closed you should be reading the question, seeing if the question merits closure, and if it doesn't, voting to reopen.  Yes, looking at what was fixed in an edit, or what someone has said in a comment might help you figure this out *more quickly* but fundamentally such information is only there as a hint for you, not something you need to figure out the answer.

If a question is closed as unclear, and you think that it's clear and otherwise acceptable as it is, and doesn't need to be improved to merit being open, you should be voting to reopen, even if it wasn't edited.  The same applies to every other close reason.

If other people disagree with you and the question ends up being closed again, then those people are of course free to cast such votes.  If you feel that the question is acceptable, but that it could be improved even more such that it would be less likely to be closed in the future, consider editing the question yourself to help others see what you are seeing in the question.  Keep in mind that it's also possible that others are seeing problems that you *aren't* seeing, or perhaps have a different standard of what they consider acceptable, and they are free to use their votes accordingly, just like you are with yours.

That's part of the design of the site; everyone casts their own votes based on their own views of a post, and at the end of the day the community's consensus wins out.  (This applies for both up/down votes, as well as close/reopen votes.)

Comment: @Jon Clements commented that a user can vote to close/reopen once per question, is that true after reopening, users can't close again the question?

Comment: @user7294900 No, it's not.  A user can only vote to close a question once, and a user can only vote to reopen a question once, but a user can both vote to close a question and vote to reopen it.  (And a moderator can of course close/reopen vote as many times as they want.)